# can excess of exercise be dangerous to dogs?

Tags: health, exercise

My female dog likes to play. A lot.

In the house, she never gets enough. In the daycare, she is always the first one up and the last one out, and will play pretty much non stop except for sleeping

The issue is that sometimes she spends more then a day in daycare (for example, if we travel for the weekend)

This last week, she spent 3 out of 4 days in daycare. When she got back home, she was tired a whole day and the better part of the next day.

Can this be dangerous? She has 1.5 years

Answer (score 2):

As far as I'm aware, there is no clear yes or no answer to your question.

Usually any animal should be aware enough of things like its energy level or muscle sorenes to get enough rest. However, how much "enough rest" is for each dog differs and some may have so much fun playing around that they chose some muscle sorenes over rest. If your dog has no underlying medical problem this should be safe.

However, there's a well-known risk of potentially lethal [intestinal twisting](https://www.thevet.co.uk/pet-advice/exercise-meal-can-really-bad-dog/) if dogs play very actively right after feeding. Every day care should know about this and separate dogs during feeding and for 2 hours after.

It can also be problematic if your dog develops an obsession (like OCD) and cannot calm down despite feeling low on energy. A typical OCD behavior is chasing shadows or specks of reflected light. If you notice any of those, you should consult a professional dog trainer as soon as possible. OCD is hard to treat in dogs and mistakes made by the owners due to not knowing how to manage it can worsen the symptoms and lead to years of suffering for the dog and humans.